# How to modify the properties in ClientRegistration registered in OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect 1.0 Provider in java?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

My question is how to modify the properties in ClientRegistration  registered in OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect 1.0 Provider? I need tenant-id and private-key not just client-id and i don't have client-secret.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to add properties like **`tenant-id`**, **`client-id`** and **`client-secret`** in your ClientRegistration registered in OAuth 2.0 Java.

You can **refer** the below code from this [**blog**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html):

```ini
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauth.provider=OAuth2provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauthprovider.scope=scope
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauthprovider.clientId=CLIENT_ID
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauthprovider.clientSecret=CLIENT_SECRET
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauthprovider.clientAuthenticationMethod=client_secret_post
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauthprovider.authorizationGrantType=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauthprovider.redirectUri=Redirect_uri
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oauthprovider.userInfoUri=User_Info_uri
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oauthprovider.userNameAttribute=name
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oauthprovider.authorization-uri=authorization_endpoint_uri
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oauthprovider.token-uri=token_endpoint_uri
```

You create the **client secret** as below:

[image]

Or you can make use of **Certificates** instead of client secret like below:

[image]

**References:**

[30. Security (spring.io)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-security.html)

[spring-boot-oauth2-login/application.properties at master · wonwoo/spring-boot-oauth2-login by wonwoo](https://github.com/wonwoo/spring-boot-oauth2-login/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties)

Comment: Thanks for help .I don't have Client secret  as i mentioned in question Instead I have certificate any idea how to use it .